# How to convert a ROS message file to an IDL file?

Tags: ros, ros2, rosmessage, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the terminal command to convert a ros message file to an idl file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400827/how-to-convert-a-ros-message-file-to-an-idl-file?/) by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2022-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosidl_adapter` core package exposes both scripts and an API to perform these conversions. For your case, use the `msg2idl.py` script:

`ros2 run rosidl_adapter msg2idl.py /path/to/msg/file`

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2022-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2022-05-19**:
Thank you!